# Using LINQ to parse the numbers from a string

Tags: c#, linq, string, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

Is it possible to write a query where we get all those characters that could be parsed into int from any given string?

For example we have a string like: `"$%^DDFG 6 7 23 1"`

Result must be `"67231"`

And even slight harder: Can we get only first three numbers?

Comment: The exact requirement is not entirely clear, what would happen with a string like`123abc456def`, do you want to return `123456`, `123` and `456`, just `123` or perhaps `1` and `2` and `3` etc?

The best approach depends on the exact spec.

Comment: @Paul it says first three numbers. How that possibly could be more exact? Maybe you'd like me to write 300 pages of specs and some sort of a business plan with bunch of diagrams? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will give you your string

```
string result = new String("y0urstr1ngW1thNumb3rs".
    Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```

And for the first 3 chars use `.Take(3)` before `ToArray()`

Comment: I don't remember who answered with this solution first. Anyway I vote here too. Besides Alan has more that 10k score.

Answer (score 11):

The following should work.

```
var myString = "$%^DDFG 6 7 23 1";

//note that this is still an IEnumerable object and will need
// conversion to int, or whatever type you want.
var myNumber = myString.Where(a=>char.IsNumber(a)).Take(3);
```

It's not clear if you want `23` to be considered a single number sequence, or 2 distinct numbers. My solution above assumes you want the final result to be `672`

Comment: You can write the where as `.Where(char.IsNumber)` I think since it accepts a char and returns a bool - no need for the lamda.

Comment: @Rup: Cool. Learned something new.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static string DigitsOnly(string strRawData)
  {
     return Regex.Replace(strRawData, "[^0-9]", "");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string testString = "$%^DDFG 6 7 23 1";
string cleaned = new string(testString.ToCharArray()
    .Where(c => char.IsNumber(c)).Take(3).ToArray());
```

If you want to use a white list (not always numbers):

```
char[] acceptedChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
string cleaned = new string(testString.ToCharArray()
    .Where(c => acceptedChars.Contains(c)).Take(3).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
var yourstring = "$%^DDFG 6 7 23 1";  
var selected = yourstring.ToCharArray().Where(c=> c >= '0' && c <= '9').Take(3);
var reduced = yourstring.Where(char.IsDigit).Take(3);
```

Comment: I guess it could be if you don't know LINQ and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
private int ParseInput(string input)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\d+");
    string valueString = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in r.Matches(input))
        valueString += match.Value;
    return Convert.ToInt32(valueString);
}
```

> And even slight harder: Can we get
>   only first three numbers?

```
    private static int ParseInput(string input, int take)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\d+");
        string valueString = string.Empty;
        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in r.Matches(input))
            valueString += match.Value;
        valueString = valueString.Substring(0, Math.Min(valueString.Length, take));
        return Convert.ToInt32(valueString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> 'string strRawData="12#$%33fgrt$%$5"; 
> string[] arr=Regex.Split(strRawData,"[^0-9]"); int a1 = 0; 
> foreach (string value in arr) { Console.WriteLine("line no."+a1+" ="+value); a1++; }'

Output:line no.0 =12
line no.1 =
line no.2 =
line no.3 =33
line no.4 =
line no.5 =
line no.6 =
line no.7 =
line no.8 =
line no.9 =
line no.10 =5
Press any key to continue . . .
```