# 11-character Social Security Number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have written the code but i am stuck on for the Social security number(SSN) if-condition.
I want SSN should be 11 characters with hyphen sign, if SSN not then display error message. 
Which convert class should I use for SSN.
Here is my code:

```
double SSN;

Console.Write("Enter you Social Security Number: ");

SSN = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

// Social Security Number Check
if (SSN != 11)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Social Security Number.");
}
```

Comment: "123-456-7890" is *not* a double, it is a string.  So don't try to store it in a variable of type Double.

Comment: Also, there are many strings with length 11 that are not a valid SSN.

Comment: @user All other code is irrelevant to your question and does not affect this code, please leave it out.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, some social security numbers have leading zeros, so if you have length test, convert to number and then back to string, you would get 10 characters which could fail your 11 length test.  http://www.usgennet.org/usa/ne/topic/resources/basic/ssn.html

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are best used to determine if a number such as Social Security Number is valid or not; a validation of it so to speak.

Here is an example which catches the user trying to add non digits, put in incorrect total number digits, as well as rejecting some obviously bad SSNs like 666 or 000.

Note this is based on the current US Gov spec for numbers, see [Social Security Number Randomization](http://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomization.html).

```
var pattern = @"                # To use this regex pattern specify IgnoreWhiteSpace due to these comments.
    ^                           # Beginning of line anchor      
    (?!9)                       # Can't be 900- 999 so stop match                                  
    (?!000)                     # If it starts with 000 its bad (STOP MATCH!)
    (?!666)                     # If it starts with 666 its bad (STOP MATCH!)
    (?<FIRST>\d{3})             # Match the First three digits and place into First named capture group
    (?:[\s\-]?)                 # Match but don't capture a possible space or dash
    (?<SECOND>\d\d)             # Match next two digits
    (?:[\s-]?)                  # Match but don't capture a possible space or dash
    (?<THIRD>\d{4})             # Match the final for digits
    $                           # EOL anchor

        ";

Console.WriteLine (Regex.IsMatch("123-45-6789", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)); // True
Console.WriteLine (Regex.IsMatch("123-45-678A", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)); // False
```

The option to `IgnorePatternWhitespace` only allows us to comment the pattern, it does not affect the regex parsing in anyway.

This answer is based on a blog post I have written and updated entitled [Regular Expression Pattern for SSN using the Match Invalidator (?!) in .Net](http://omegacoder.com/?p=30)

Comment: If you [copy your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10034644/266143), don't you think it's better to close-vote as duplicate?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure I provided an answer on a different question which was "Looking for a cleaner RegEx solution to matching different formats for a SSN:" which has SSN involved, but the answer given above is pointing out how *to use Regex*, and how a regex pattern could be *applied*. Stack Overflow encourages examples and not links...so which is better, my providing a current example or a link to the original or flagging the user for an answer I could give which I have given before? I decided to provide an example.

Comment: For numbers issued since 2011, the area number (first three digits) may be any three digit number from 001 - 899, excluding 666.  This regex will incorrectly identify SSNs beginning with 773 through 899 as being invalid (as well as 703-709, 713-719, ..., 763-769, which would have been valid even before the change).  (Ref. http://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomization.html)

Comment: @drf Thanks, I have updated the pattern to handle the easier government specification.

Answer (score 1):

With `SSN != 11` you're not comparing the *length* of `SSN` with 11, but its *value*. As it is a numeric type, in this case a `double`, the user will have to literally enter `11` in order to pass the SSN test.

You can regard it as a string:

```
string ssn = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then you could [use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792242/regex-to-get-number-only-from-string) or [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480588/using-linq-to-parse-the-numbers-from-a-string) to get only the numbers from the string, ignoring any other characters that may be entered:

```
ssn = new String(ssn.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```

After which you can inspect [`ssn.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify it has 9 digits.

Whether those digits form a valid SSN, is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517026/how-can-i-validate-us-social-security-number).

Comment: thanks for your help. but i can't use ToArray() as my prof. has not taught us.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your SSN:");
        string SSN = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] SSN_numbers = new int[3];
        try
        {
            String[] numbers = SSN.Split('-');
            if (numbers.Length != 3) throw new Exception("SSN is not in correct format!");
            for (int i = 0; i != 3; i++)
            {
                SSN_numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]);
            }

            // do what you want with your numbers here...
            Console.WriteLine("first number: {0}", SSN_numbers[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("second number: {0}", SSN_numbers[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("third number: {0}", SSN_numbers[2]);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SSN is not in correct format!");
        }
```